# Android Get/Set Value to an ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-xml

I have an ImageView as such:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/p4"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:onClick="getPriority"
    android:value="P4"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ContentDescription_fromAddItemActivity_Priority4Icon"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_priority_4"/>
```

I want to get the value "P4" programatically. How do i do that ?

I've already tried ".getValue()" and it doesn't exists.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use **`android:tag="P4"`**

Comment: tag will be better for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `android:value="P4"` You can use `android:tag="P4"` and then you can use `getTag()` and `setTag()` methods of it.